# Table content replaced with new one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

If I click on the submit button, then insert new cell, and click more than one time cells inserts again and again in a table i want to only add items only one time in table not again and again.

i want to call clear previous  data and add new one when call fillTable().
my code is below here

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="fillTable()" value="submit">

    <div id="out" >
        <h2>Results are</h2>
        <table id="tblData" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Share</th>
            </tr>
            </table>

    </div>
    <script>

        function fillTable(){
             clearCells(); // clear previous
            var tableRef = document.getElementById("tblData");
            var rowcount = tableRef.rows.length;
            var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(rowcount);

            // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
            var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
            var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
            var newText1  = document.createTextNode("Hello");
            var newText2  = document.createTextNode("12000");

            newCell.appendChild(newText1);
            newCell2.appendChild(newText2);

            newCell.appendChild(newText1);
            newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
        }

        function clearCells(){
            var tableRef = document.getElementById("tblData");
            tableRef.deleteCell(0);
            tableRef.deleteCell(1);

        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, please explain what you want to happen, what actually happens and a jsFiddle if you can.

Comment: i am re edit the question i hope you can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem was in your clearCell method, I fixed it for you:

```
function clearCells(){
   var tableRef = document.getElementById("tblData");
   if(tableRef.rows.length > 1){
      tableRef.deleteRow(1);
   }
}
```